# How to upload a file in Swift Storage system using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack-swift

I want to upload a file in Swift. I executed this code in python :

```
 import swiftclient
swift = swiftclient.client.Connection(auth_version='1',user='test:tester',key='testing',authurl='http://localhost:8080/auth/v1.0')
# Create the swift container
swift.put_container('cute-cats')
# Upload the object
with open('cat.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    file_data = f.read()
swift.put_object('cute-cats', 'cat.jpg', file_data)

# List the containers
print swift.head_account()

# List the objects in the cute cats containers
print swift.head_container('cute-cats')
```

The code is running, but, how can I check if the file is stored in swift ? The file does not exist in the folder Swift.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From terminal you can run a simple curl:

$ curl  http://localhost:8080/v1/AUTH_test/cute-cats/cat.jpg

If you want to test using python code, you can use the lib requests[1](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

> The file does not exist in the folder Swift.

Which folder do you mean? Swift usually store its objects(files) using a hash, so to find the objects you gonna need a command like swift-get-nodes.